# Programmatically add columns to a DBSet in Entity Framework 6, EF Core for .NET 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In our app we use .net Framework 4.8, and soon will move to .net6

We are moving to a multi tenant architecture where each tenant will have their own database, most tables being identical between tenants. However some tables will be modified in the field by the tenant adding user defined columns.

I have studied EF OnModelCreating, and I see ways to re map between fields, rename field, etc. What I cant find is a way to programmatically add columns to an existing DBSet

Since we will soon move to .net6 please consider how to do so in that environment.

Example - db.SimpleTable has columns Id, Name

Column ProductNumber is added at runtime by the tenant.

Now the class defined within EF for SimpleTable has Id, Name, but how does one programmatically add ProductNumber at the point of creating the dbContext such that changes to it are mapped, fetched, and updated, without creating a new SimpleTable class and linking it in?

Comment: *tenant adding user defined columns* - get them to add rows instead and pivot it if you really need them to be columns, but generally, I can't see a need for it. Block of key value pairs would work well. DB Columns == C# Properties; to leverage them as EF wants to, you recompile the app with new props. Better to add rows; rows == object instances- can have as many as you like without recompiling

Comment: You better advise your supervisor to change db  using Sql management studio before you started  migration, since net 4 and net 6 are very different

Comment: Allowing people to add columns is a recipe for disaster. Instead, you can give options for storing data in a known schema that allows for customers to add more dynamic data, like key/value tables. Another option would be to store data in a JSON file and add that to a column, or store it outside the database.

Comment: Check out shadow and indexer properties.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties